# How to not repeat this same function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
  const postDate = (fullDate) => {
    return `${fullDate.split(" ").splice(1, 2).join(" ")}, 
      ${fullDate.split(" ").splice(3, 1).join(" ")}`;
  };
```

I have repeated the above function on three different pages.
Any suggestion to not reapeat the same code or any way to export the function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file, say, `postDate.js`

```js
const postDate = (fullDate) => {
    return `${fullDate.split(" ").splice(1, 2).join(" ")}, 
      ${fullDate.split(" ").splice(3, 1).join(" ")}`;
};

export default postDate
```

Now inside a file where you want to use the function, import the function and use it. Like so:

```js
import postDate from './path/to/postDate.js'
// do note that is path will be relative to the current file's location

...
postDate(dt)
...
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. What should I name the folder with functions

Comment: @sanggam10 You can use `utils`, short for utilities.

Comment: @sanggam10 kindly mark the answer as correct if it helped you. If not, feel free to ask what's not clear. Will happily explain.